# Is there a way to distinguish the device context type?

Tags: winapi, hook, gdi

I am Hooking the GDI API ExtTextOut

```
BOOL ExtTextOut(
  __in  HDC hdc,
  __in  int X,
  __in  int Y,
  __in  UINT fuOptions,
  __in  const RECT *lprc,
  __in  LPCTSTR lpString,
  __in  UINT cbCount,
  __in  const INT *lpDx
);
```

My question: Is there a good solid way to distinguish the device context type (HDC).
In particular to know if it is a memory device context or a display device context.

Thanks for your efforts,
Momico.

Comment: How did you *get* the device context? That's the easiest way to tell the difference. Otherwise, what's the usage case? Maybe there's a better way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't know because it is not a device context that I have created but one that I recieved as a parameter from the hooked ExtTextOut function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

off course there is, you should put in your custom function 
return GetObjectType( dc ) == OBJ_MEMDC ;

best